# Dynamically create CAML query

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

I have a serach page which earlier was function on SQL DB but now we moved the back-en to SharePoint, I am trying to build a query based upon user select from drop-down box.

Existing SQL query was :

```
string SQLquery "Select companyname,phone,email from Tab where Approved = 1"

If (country.selectedindex != "")
{
   SQLquery += "AND (country LIKE '%" + country.SelectedValue + "%')"
}
If (functional.selectedindex != "")
{
   SQL += "AND (country LIKE '%" + country.SelectedValue + "%')"
}
If (state.selectedindex != "")
{
   SQL += "AND (state LIKE '%" + state.SelectedValue + "%') OR ( businessareaState like '%" + state.SelectedValue + "%'))"
}
```

This was easy, but I have to create the same query in CAML based upon user selection form the drop-down lists.
Somehow I am not able to give it a dynamic shape since the structure changes completely in the CAML as soon as you add and criteria in it.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 or MOSS 2007? if 2010 have you looked at linq? I think It will be simpler.

Comment: +1 as LINQ to CAML can be great, but it has pitfalls in the magic that happens beind the scenes http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/09/08/linq-to-sharepoint-performance-pitfalls/

Comment: I haven't yet, I'll definitely do it now, thanks for timely reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this free tool to help build your CAML queries

http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx

Do a few variations on your query and you will see how the structure changes. Basically you will have to build up an XML document rather than use string concatenation (though that can work as well, it will probably be simpler to build it in an XML parser)

Comment: Ryan I am using it already, yes its a bit tricky but I have figured that the best way to work with dynamic query is to hard code it only, as it changes the whole structure as soon as you add and clause to the query.

Answer (score 3):

I have developed C# code to build dynamic query.
Its like this

```
 public string GenerateQuery(IList<CamlQueryElements> lstOfElement)
    {
        StringBuilder queryJoin = new StringBuilder();
        string query = @"<{0}><FieldRef Name='{1}' /><Value {2} Type='{3}'>{4}</Value></Eq>";
        if (lstOfElement.Count > 0)
        {
            int itemCount = 0;
            foreach (CamlQueryElements element in lstOfElement)
            {
                itemCount++;
                string date = string.Empty;
                // Display only Date
                if (String.Compare(element.FieldType, "DateTime", true) == 0)
                    date = "IncludeTimeValue='false'";
                queryJoin.AppendFormat(string.Format(query, element.ComparisonOperators,
                                element.FieldName, date, element.FieldType, element.FieldValue));

                if (itemCount >= 2)
                {
                    queryJoin.Insert(0, string.Format("<{0}>", element.LogicalJoin));
                    queryJoin.Append(string.Format("</{0}>", element.LogicalJoin));
                }
            }
            queryJoin.Insert(0, "<Where>");
            queryJoin.Append("</Where>");
        }
        return queryJoin.ToString();
    }
```

IList lstOfElement is custom object which holds filter elements. You can create your own object and pass into this method.

Comment: You can use the below class:

public class CamlQueryElements
    {
        public string FieldName;
        public string FieldType;
        public string FieldValue;
        public string ComparisonOperators;
        public string LogicalJoin;
    }